# Regex accepting alphabets from languages like Å,Ø or र

Tags: regex

I need a reg ex which would accept everything except white spaces,followed by @(only one occurrence) and then everything except white spaces.

Eg- abc@abc

By everything I mean here is all characters including characters like Norwegian or Nordic language alphabets,or any other language.

I tried this...
^\S[^@]+\b@\b\S[^@]+$
but this would fail for characters like Ø@Ø, Å@Å or र@र...

Edit-I want this for javascript...

Comment: Which regex flavour are you using (egrep, perl, php)?

Comment: Look here for unicode categories. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something easier like:

```
^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+$
```

?
`[^@\s]+` matches everything except `@` or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: did you try to run this regex for "a@a", "b@b", "c@c"? Because it fails, too :).
Your regex expect one non-space and at least one not-@ before @.
The correct regex should be:

```
^\S+\b@\S+$
```

The other thing that may be messing with your results is encoding of the script in which you keep your regex. If it's not unicode, there may be some problems. But I'm not sure. What are you using to run the regex? npp? php?